# Adding String to Inner Bundle output Null Exception

Tags: android

I'm using this simple Android code and getting Null Exception for "myBundle" when geting to this line:
"myBundle.putstring....".
Thank you for your help.

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity{
Bundle myBundle;

 @override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
   Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
   btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    @override
    public void onClick(View v){
      myBundle.putstring("someKey","someString");
    }
  });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to instantiate your myBundle variable before you use it.

```
Bundle myBundle = new Bundle();
```